# ¿Cómo comparar dos secuencias, retornando los elementos que coinciden?

Tags: python, comparaciones

Hola estuve intentando y no estoy pudiendo.

Tengo que armar y ejecutar un comando el cual compare dos secuencias y me devuelva las letras que coinciden.

La consigna del ejercicio es la siguiente:

> diferencias (secuencia1, secuencia2): esta función recibe dos secuencias y debe devolver una nueva cadena de caracteres conteniendo aquellas bases donde coincidan ambas secuencias y en caso contrario se marque con un guión. Si son de diferente largo, completar con "*" Ejemplo: recibe: "ATGGATGG", "ANGCTTGCNN", retorna: "A-G--TG-**"

Esto es lo que intente hacer:

```
sec1 = input("ingrese una secuencia")
sec2 = input("ingrese una secuencia")
for i in range of(sec1,sec2):
  if sec1[i] == sec2[i] :         #Dice que si la base de en la posicion i es igual a la posicion i+1
  print(i)
```

Comment: Hola Rafaela, bienvenida, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola! Qué problema tiene tu código? Por qué dices que no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

```
secuencia1 = "ATGGATGG"
secuencia2 = "ANGCTTGCNN"

def diferencias( secuencia1, secuencia2 ):
    largoCorta = min( [ len( secuencia1 ), len( secuencia2 ) ] ) 
    largoLarga = max( [ len( secuencia1 ), len( secuencia2 ) ] ) 
    salida = ""
    for i in range( largoLarga ):
        if i >= largoCorta:
                salida += "*" 
        else:
            if secuencia1[ i ] == secuencia2[ i ]:
                salida += secuencia1[ i ] 
            else:
                salida += "-" 
    return salida

print( diferencias( secuencia1, secuencia2 ))
```

Como verás, el código es bastante sencillito.
Primero creamos dos variables, que serán inicializadas con el largo de la cadena más larga y el de la más corta respectivamente.
Estos valores los necesitamos para saber cuando abandonamos la zona de comparación (una de las cadenas no tiene más letras) y hasta donde tenemos que iterar (cantidad de letras de la cadena más larga).
Luego creamos una cadena vacía, que será la que devolvamos.
Dentro del `for` no ha mucho que explicar, primero verificamos que **`i`** no sobrepase el largo de la cadena corta, si lo hace, agregamos un asterisco a la cadena **salida**, sino, verificamos que las letras contenidas en la actual posición de ambas cadenas coincidan, si lo hacen, agregamos la letra a **salida** sino, agregamos un guión.
Solo resta devolver la cadena.
Es importante el orden de los `if` dentro del bucle, ya que si intentamos invertir el orden, terminaremos pidiendo a una de las dos cadenas, una posición más allá de su longitud, lo que nos arrojará un error.

Comment: Considera dejar algunos espacios cuando creas conveniente. Hará más amena la lectura. Sino quien lo lea le dará la sensación de que es más largo de lo que realmente es.